# Using Derivatives to Approximate Changes in a Function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

We know that $\Delta{f(x)}\approx f^\prime(x)\Delta{x}$. I’m looking to formalise this argument (it may have been formalised already, but here’s my approach). Firstly, say we want to find $f(b)-f(a)$. Using the approximation stated earlier, $f(b)-f(a)\approx f^\prime(\frac{a+b}{2})(b-a)$. Note that I’m evaluating the derivative at the arithmetic mean of $a$ and $b$. I find that this works well for a few simple functions. Perhaps, evaluating it at the geometric or harmonic mean may be better in some situations. Anyway, to formalise this argument I thought of proving that $\lim_{b \to\ a} \frac{f^\prime(\frac{a+b}{2})(b-a)}{f(b)-f(a)}=1$. My reasoning is that as $b$ tends to $a$, $\frac{\Delta{f(x)}}{\Delta{x}}$ tends to $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$, and the approximation tends to the actual value of the change in the function. Is there any flaw in my reasoning? Can this formalisation somehow be improved? Also, how to prove the limit stated above? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your reasoning cannot be mathematically rigorous if you use the symbol " $\approx$ ". Also you say you want to formalise your approximation but you are using it to proove it... It's logically wrong. If you are looking for a proper theorem, what you are looking for is called the Taylor's theorem (first order).

Comment: The whole point of introducing limits was to remove that symbol. Also, I’m looking to prove that the limit evaluates to 1 only if my reasoning is true, which it may or may not be. Thanks for the reference to Taylor’s Theorem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the definition (or an equivalent way of writing the definition) of differentiability of $f$ at $x$ is that $\Delta f(x;h):=f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(x)h+ R(x;h)$, where $R(x;h)=f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h$ is the remainder term, and is small in the sense that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{R(x;h)}{h}=0$. This is the formal way of saying things. In words, we're saying that the actual change in the function $f$ at the point $x$, when displaced by an amount $h$, is equal to a linear term $f'(x)h$, plus some excess remainder, whereby the remainder is 'small' in the sense described above. People often call this a "first order Taylor expansion", but really it's just the definition of the derivative.

Your approach of using the arithmetic mean and dividing requires some extra assumptions, which are stronger than merely assuming differentiability at a single point $x$. For the purposes, you may find this convenient (I don't), but you should think more closely about the definition I wrote above. Differential calculus is essentially the subject of linear approximations, so internalizing the above idea will take you very far.

---

**Edit:**

In response to the comment, your limit is true but under stronger hypotheses:

> If $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is **continuously differentiable** and $a\in\Bbb{R}$ is a point such that $f'(a)\neq 0$, then for all $b$ in a punctured nighborhood of $a$, we have $f(b)-f(a)\neq 0$, and $\lim\limits_{b\to a}\frac{f'\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)(b-a)}{f(b)-f(a)}=1$.

Note the stronger assumptions. We are assuming here that $f$ is not only differentiable in an interval around $a$, but also that the derivative is continuous there. To prove this, note that first of all $f'(a)\neq 0$, and continuity of $f'$ at $a$ implies that $f'$ maintains a constant sign near $a$ (i.e $f'$ is positive near $a$, or $f'$ is negative near $a$). So, $f$ is strictly monotone near $a$, and thus $f(b)-f(a)\neq 0$.

This paragraph above doesn't get to the heart of the theorem, but it is an important first step to ensure that the fraction we're talking about in the limit actually makes sense (we must avoid division by $0$ at all costs). Now, here's what we can write: if $b$ is in a small punctured neighborhood of $a$, then
\begin{align}
\frac{f'\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)(b-a)}{f(b)-f(a)}&=
\frac{f'\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)}{\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}}
\end{align}
Now in the numerator, we have $\frac{a+b}{2}\to a$ as $b\to a$, and so by continuity of $f'$, we have $f'\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\to f'(a)$. The denominator approaches $f'(a)$, as $b\to a$, by definition of the derivative. Thus, the quotient approaches $\frac{f'(a)}{f'(a)}=1$ (I'm using the theorem that limit of quotients equals quotient of limits, provided all the limits exist and the limit of denominator is non-zero).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am only interested in the $f^\prime(x)h$ part, and not the remainder part, as I feel that investigating functions using their approximations could be interesting. Do you know if the assertion about the limit I made is true? If so, how do I go about proving it?

Comment: @Heisenberg I've provided a precise statement and proof.

Comment: That’s simply perfect. It’s just what I wanted. Now that I know how to evaluate the limit I’m annoyed that I didn’t figure it out myself. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This $$\lim_{b \to\ a} \frac{f^\prime(\frac{a+b}{2})(b-a)}{f(b)-f(a)}=1$$ could be false without the hypothesis of $f'$ being continuous.

If you add that hypothesis, then proving it is almost trivial (may be you could try it).

Comment: I am assuming that $f$ is continuous, and that $\frac{a+b}{2},a,$and $b$ are all in the function’s domain. I did try proving it, but I didn’t get too far. In fact, I asked a friend of mine if he could help me with it, and he couldn’t figure it out either. This is what led me to believe that there’s some sort of flaw in my reasoning.

Comment: @Heisenberg You're assuming **more** than just continuity when you speak about $f'$. You're implicitly assuming differentiability (which is stronger than continuity), otherwise it makes no sense to talk about $f'$. But in my answer I talk about the even stronger hypothesis: the continuity **of the derivative**

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn’t see the $\prime$. Thanks for your input.